# Apache FOP generated PDFs printing strangely from Adobe Reader; OK on screen

Tags: perl, printing, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm not sure how this can be a FOP issue, but I've never seen it with PDFs from any other source, so I've tried to investigate further.

Our application creates PDFs via xsl-fo, using FOP. This has worked great for a couple of years -- occasionally a user will have trouble printing a specific document, and see a very particular type of corruption, wherein most characters are "incremented". That is to say, 1 becomes 2, M becomes N, period becomes a slash, and the word invoice becomes the mildly amusing "jowpjdf". The document displays fine (typically in Adobe Reader). We've generally worked around it, but now an even odder case presents itself.

A new addition to our application creates 2 substantially similar PDFs created with FOP, then concatenates them using Perl's PDF::Reuse to grab the files from the filesystem and create a new document, which is then sent to the user by email. User opens document fine in Reader, hits print, and something new happens... Page 1 prints perfectly, but page 2 is corrupt in exactly the manner described above.

If it was a consistent print driver issue, I'd expect to see both pages corrupted. If it was a FOP issue, likewise. If it was a PDF::Reuse issue, I'd expect to see more fundamental breakage, and this breakage is not new since we started concatenating documents. I'm at a loss where to investigate next.

Has anyone seen similar corruption in PDFs, especially when generating using Apache FOP?

**tl;dr PDFs created using FOP sometimes print with every character shifted by 1, e.g. A->B, 3->4**

Comment: Bonus information: seems to be at least partially print driver related. The specific Xerox driver for a Colorqube 9201 always prints with the problem, using the Xerox Global PCL6 driver works sometimes!

Still, I've only seen this in FOP-produced PDFs, so I don't think that's completely unrelated... Just a quirk which is in turn triggering odd print driver behaviour.